# What's wrong with my code parsing the kml to Google Earth?

Tags: java, javascript, kml, google-earth-plugin

In can't parse the kml to my GE, whats wrong with my code?

I'm stuck at this for 2 weeks and tried myself to do many others ways,

Any help will be welcome,

Rafael Jesus

google_earth.jsp

```
var ge;  

google.load("earth", "1");  

function init() {  
    google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);  
    window.scroll(0, 10000);  
}  

function initCB(instance) {  
    ge = instance;  
    ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);  

    // add a navigation control  
    ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_AUTO);  

    // add some layers  
    ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_BORDERS, true);  
    ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_ROADS, true);  

    // directs the exact location of the placemark  
    var lookAt = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);  
    lookAt.setLatitude(-15.26108113514467);  
    lookAt.setLongitude(-57.77290131815782);  
    lookAt.setRange(8007066.726300671);  

    ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);  
    ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_TERRAIN, false);  

    var kmlString = showPics();  
    // I put a alert in here and show in a window the value "undefined"  
    var kmlObject = ge.parseKml( kmlString );  
    ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
```

}

```
// dwr function that brings the kml with his values  
            // for now it is in hard coded, just for tests!!  
    function showPics() {  
        PainelEarthAjax.geraFotosObra({  
            callback : function(kmlString) {  
                            // I put a alert function in here, and it has openned a window  
                            // with the entire kmlString brought from the java method geraFotosObra().  
                    return kmlString;  
            }  
        });  
    }  

function failureCB(errorCode) {  

}    
google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
```

geraFotosObra.java

```
public String geraFotosObra () throws Exception {  
    try {  
        return new KMLGenerator().getKMLFromObra();  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);  
        return null;  
    }  
}
```

KMLGenerator.java

```
public static String getKMLFromObra () {  
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();  
    sb.append("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>");  
    sb.append("<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' ");  

    sb.append("<Document>");  
    sb.append("<name>ConstruMobil</name>");  

    sb.append("<Style id='defaultStyles'>");  
    sb.append("<IconStyle>");  
    sb.append("<Icon>");  
    sb.append("<href>" + "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal4/icon38.png" + "</href>");  
    sb.append("</Icon>");  
    sb.append("</IconStyle>");  
    sb.append("</Style>");  
    sb.append("</Style>");  

    sb.append("<Placemark>");  
    sb.append("<name>" + "Some name" + "</name>");  
    sb.append("<styleUrl>" + "#defaultStyles"+ "</styleUrl>");  
    sb.append("<altitudeMode>" + "relativeToGround" + "</altitudeMode>");  

    sb.append("<Location>");  
    sb.append("<longitude>" + -122.3599987260313 + "</longitude>");  
    sb.append("<latitude>" + 47.62949781133496 + "</latitude>");  
    sb.append("<altitude>"+ 15.49615401024533 + "</altitude>");  
    sb.append("</Location>");  

    sb.append("<Link>");  
    sb.append("<href>" + "http://localhost:8080/myCompany/lib/img/dubai.jpg" + "</href>");  
    sb.append("</Link>");  
    sb.append("</Model>");  
    sb.append("</Placemark>");  

    sb.append("</Document>");  
    sb.append("</kml>");  

    return sb.toString();  
}
```

Comment: what is your error? can you narrow it down?

Comment: Paste the kml output from your method into a textfile and nicely ident it and you'll see it's goofed up. First obvious one I see is that you have a /Model (endtag) without a corresponding starttag

Comment: man tks first, i got the msg "kml is undefined", i decreases my kml just for tests and i got that message, i've already tested in kml interactive the same kml i got in my app and it worked there

Comment: Hi Pointy, may you suggest something at this one? [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329945/whats-the-best-pratice-to-show-multiple-placemarks-with-photos-inside-of-the-bal

Answer (score 1):

The `getKMLFromObra()` function doesn't return a valid XML :

The closing bracket `>` is missing in the opening `<kml ...>` tag :

```
sb.append("<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' ");
```

should be

```
sb.append("<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>");
```

To avoid errors like this in the generated XML you should consider using specialized java classes instead of String concatenation, here are some exemple of XML generation with `DOM` or `SAX` : http://www.javazoom.net/services/newsletter/xmlgeneration.html

Answer (score 0):

`showPics()` does not return a result. you return your result inside the `callback` function. Try this:

```
function showPics(ge) {  
    PainelEarthAjax.geraFotosObra({  
        callback : function(kmlString) {  
            var kmlObject = ge.parseKml(kmlString);  
            ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);  
        }  
    });  
}
```

Then call it up like this:

```
ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);  
ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_TERRAIN, false);  

showPics(ge);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding guys,

I've already fix the ">" problem, now i got the message "kml is not defined"

I've already tested on [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/interactive/index.html

And it worked fine, it showed my photo on the test,

Im almost there, What else?

Tks a lot

Comment: Hi epoch, may you suggest something at this one? [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329945/whats-the-best-pratice-to-show-multiple-placemarks-with-photos-inside-of-the-bal

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `</Style>` close tag, and a floating `</Model>` close tag, with no actual `Model` element.

You can check output with an XML validator, something like [Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) or even just using the XML bundle in TextMate.

Comment: I've already fix it Mano, now the message is "kml is undefined!", but my kml is Ok, cuz i've tested it on kml interective, any help will be welcome..tks

Comment: are you validating it against the OGC KML Schema? http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd

Comment: Mano i didin't understand, what u mean validationg Schema? All i know is to validate Shema is when ur using Web Services, how do i do that, im sorry about lack of knowledge!

Comment: So, an XML schema describes the form of the document. It describes what elements can be in it, in what order, and using what namespaces. Here's a bit more information, if you're using Oxygen: http://www.oxygenxml.com/validation.html That message says to me that whatever you're trying to use is saying that kml isn't defined because you're not designating a schema to define it.

Comment: Remove each of the semi-colons, add in http:// before each of the namespaces, like xmlns='http://opengis.net/kml/2.2'. You should learn more about XML, try searching for an XML tutorial.

Comment: This is unbelievable, in my code I have the http:// before the namespace, and in my code of course I do not have the ";" I pasted the placemark here when I was debugging in eclipse, I copied the debug and pasted, and immediately, the same placemark that I pasted here, also pasted in kml interactive, and worked there...

Comment: Mano I got it working, now it takes to the earth what i have declared on placemark...my problem was trusting too much in eclipseI just delete it and installed it again and it worked....Many tks

Comment: Sure. Please accept the answer so that this no longer shows up as unanswered.

Comment: Hi Mano, may you suggest something at this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329945/whats-the-best-pratice-to-show-multiple-placemarks-with-photos-inside-of-the-bal

Answer (score 0):

I got the message "kml is undefined!"

I think it is a parse problem on jsp, i've changed my getKMLFromObra() just for tests, i insert  the code below:

PS: I tested this kml on kml interactive and it worked there,

getKMLFromObra()

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>");
    sb.append("<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' >");
    sb.append("<Placemark>");
    sb.append("<name>Simple placemark</name>");
    sb.append("<description>testing fucking kml</description>");
    sb.append("<Point>");
    sb.append("<coordinates>-122.0822035425683,37.42228990140251,0</coordinates>");
    sb.append("</Point>");
    sb.append("</Placemark>");
    sb.append("</kml>");
    return sb.toString();
```

My google_earth.jsp below:

```
var ge;

google.load("earth", "1");

function init() {
    google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);
    window.scroll(0, 10000);

}

function initCB(instance) {
    ge = instance;
    ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

    // add a navigation control
    ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_AUTO);

    // add some layers
    ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_BORDERS, true);
    ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_ROADS, true);
    ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_TERRAIN, false);

    showPics(ge);
}

function showPics(ge) {
    PainelEarthAjax.geraFotosObra({
        callback : function(kmlString) {
            var kmlObject = ge.parseKml(kmlString);
            ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
        }
    });
    return null;
}

function failureCB(errorCode) {

}
google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
```