# Whats the best pratice to show multiple placemarks with photos inside of the ballons?

Tags: java, javascript, kml, google-earth-plugin

I have a project as follows: Several photos are taken from a mobile, the photos are saved in a web system, which in turn displays the photos on google earth that is inside it. I've read many articles but all of them were using fetchKml, one good article that i've read was using php, but using fetchKml. I dont know if its possible using parseKml instead. Anyway, I'm not sure how to do this with the kml, so it looks tike this:

My Class KMLGenerator()

```
public static String getKMLFromObra (List<Obra> obraFotos) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>");
    sb.append("<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' " + 
            "xmlns:gx='http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2' " + 
            "xmlns:kml='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' " + 
            "xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'> ");

    if (obraFotos != null && obraFotos.size() > 0) {
        for (Obra o : obraFotos) {
            for (Local local : o.getLocais()) {
                sb.append("<Document>");  
                sb.append("<name>" + local.getName() + "</name>");  

                sb.append("<Style id='defaultStyles'>");  
                sb.append("<IconStyle>");  
                sb.append("<scale>1.1</scale>");
                sb.append("<Icon>");  
                sb.append("<href>" + "http://localhost:8080/ConstruMobilFoto/lib/img/fotoIcon.png" + "</href>");  
                sb.append("</Icon>");  
                sb.append("</IconStyle>");  
                sb.append("</Style>");  

                sb.append("<Placemark>");  
                sb.append("<name>" + "Foto" + "</name>");  
                sb.append("<styleUrl>" + "#defaultStyles"+ "</styleUrl>");  
                sb.append("<altitudeMode>" + "relativeToGround" + "</altitudeMode>");  
                sb.append("<Point>");
                sb.append("<altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>");
                sb.append("<coordinates>" + local.getLongitude() + "," + local.getLatitude() + "," + 50</coordinates>");
                sb.append("</Point>");
                sb.append("<Link>");
                sb.append("<href>" + local.getFotos() + "</href>");
                sb.append("</Link>");

                sb.append("</Placemark>");  
                sb.append("</Document>");  
                sb.append("</kml>");  
                return sb.toString();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have a dwr function in my jsp that invokes this method, got its String results and make the parse like this:

Class PainelEarth()

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public String geraFotosObra (int idObra) throws Exception {
    try {
        List<Obra> obraFotos = obraBusiness.getObraLatLong(new Obra(idObra));
        return new KMLGenerator().getKMLFromObra(obraFotos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

and in my jsp page

```
function initCB(instance) {
    // other codes

    showPics(ge);
}

function showPics(ge) {
    PainelEarthAjax.geraFotosObra({
        callback : function(kmlString) {
            var kmlObject = ge.parseKml(kmlString);
            ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
        }
    });
    return null;
}
```

Any help will be welcome!!

Comment: I'm actually not sure what the question is, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

In your code if you look at the signature of the method `geraFotosObra` you can see it takes a single `int` parameter `idObra`.

```
public String geraFotosObra (int idObra) throws Exception { ...
```

Yet when you call the method in your jsp you are passing an an object literal containing a callback function.

```
PainelEarthAjax.geraFotosObra({
        callback : function(kmlString) { ...
```

As it is I don't see how the kml is generated, unless perhaps `geraFotosObra` is an overloaded method? Also even if it was generated, as is, I don't see how the callback function that you pass in place of an id is ever called - why for example would `kmlString` be the result of the call to `geraFotosObra`?

```
// How is this called, what sets kmlString!?
callback : function(kmlString) {
            var kmlObject = ge.parseKml(kmlString);
            ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
        }
```

All in all the code you posted is a wee bit confusing, so sorry if I have missed something...I think you have possibly copy and pasted some code from a fetchKml example and the asynchronous callbacks used with that method have confused you slightly.

Anyhow, based on what you have posted, you should be passing an `int` `id` to the `geraFotosObra` method, getting the string result and then parsing it in the plug-in.

Something like the following makes sense. Replace the `showPics` function with the following.

```
function showPics(ge) {
  var kmlString = PainelEarthAjax.geraFotosObra(1); // or something?
  var kmlObject = ge.parseKml(kmlString);
  ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
}
```